# jQuery - Set CSS dimensions according to HTML attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-7

As most of us know, there's a thing I like to call a bug in <IE7, where images don't resize when you put your dimensions only in the attributes. You need to set the CSS width and height as well. Now I've built a site without this in mind and I thought it could be solved with jQuery in a few lines. The problem is that I don't know the syntax at all and I need the solution fast. I'll dive into jQuery later, but now I need to fix it ASAP.

But please, if you write a script, comment it so I know which
line does what. Thank you in advance.

Basically, what it does is scan every img tag on the site and set CSS dimensions according to the attributes of the tag.

What I tried was this:

```
  $(function(){
    $('img').each(function() {
        this.css("width":this.attr('width'),"height":this.attr('height'));
      });
});
```

Yet nothing happens.

EDIT: Fixed with help of Arun P Johny :)

```
$(function () {
    $('img').attr("style", function () {return "width:" + $(this).attr('width') + "px;height:" + $(this).attr('height') + "px;"});
});
```

Seems to work pretty well with wordpress :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the `each` callback `this` refers to the dom element not a jQuery wrapper object so it does not have methods like `.attr()`.

But the solution you are looking for is

```
$(function () {
    $('img').css("width": function () {
        return $(this).attr('width')
    }, "height": function () {
        return $(this).attr('height')
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/mE3pr/)

Comment: Thank you. The fiddle works, but for some reason works even without the script. On the other hand, on my site, it doesnt't work even with the script. What.
Could you try to set it that the script adds the style to the style attribute?

Comment: @user2359063 the style attribute is not what have to be chaned... it is the style assigned to the element... check the inlined styles assigned to the element you could see the height and width set to it

Comment: Fixed it with altering the style attribute :3